# Django configuration: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured

Tags: python, django, mocha.js

I started a Django project, but I get an error with database settings. The homepage works fine:

```
It worked!
Congratulations on your first Django-powered page.

Of course, you haven't actually done any work yet. Next, start your first app by
running python manage.py startapp [appname].
You're seeing this message because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file 
and you haven't configured any URLs. Get to work!
```

But I get this error is console:

```
settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE
value. Check settings documentation for more details.

Request Method:     GET Request URL:    http://fireidea.net/ Django
Version:    1.6.2 Exception Type:   ImproperlyConfigured Exception Value:


settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE
value. Check settings documentation for more details.

Exception Location:
    /home2/minhhien/webapps/django/django/db/backends/dummy/base.py in
complain, line 15 Python Executable:    /usr/bin/python Python Version:
    2.7.5 
...
```

Database settings:

```
MANAGERS = ADMINS
DATABASE_ENGINE = 'mysql'
DATABASE_NAME = ''
DATABASE_USER = ''
DATABASE_PASSWORD = ''
DATABASE_HOST = 'localhost'
DATABASE_PORT = ''

#DATABASES = {
#    'default': {
#        'ENGINE': '',
#        'NAME': '',
#        'HOST': 'localhost',
#        'PORT': '',
#        'USER': '',
#        'PASSWORD': ''
#    }
#}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django 1.6 expects DATABASES to be a dictionary. 
You commented it out, and put some older settings format in there. 
You should change it back to:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': ''
    }
}
```

See more about this here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/databases/

Comment: Deploy mochahost:
http://www.mochasupport.com/kayako/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=448

Comment: @ Oz123ExtractionError: Can't extract file(s) to egg cache

The following error occurred while trying to extract file(s) to the Python egg
cache:

  [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'home2/minhhien/.python-eggs'

The Python egg cache directory is currently set to:

  home2/minhhien/.python-eggs

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  You can
change the cache directory by setting the PYTHON_EGG_CACHE environment
variable to point to an accessible directory.

Answer (score 1):

You're using settings variables `DATABASES_*` which was already [deprecated in Django 1.2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/settings/#deprecated-settings), 5 years ago now!

You need to use a dictionary, as the default setting might have pre-filled for you:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
        'USER': '<user>',
        'PASSWORD': ''
    }
}
```

Comment: Deploy mochahost:
http://www.mochasupport.com/kayako/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=448

Comment: This documentation is *really* outdated. Their Django version is up to date, but not this page...

Comment: ExtractionError: Can't extract file(s) to egg cache

The following error occurred while trying to extract file(s) to the Python egg
cache:

  [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'home2/minhhien/.python-eggs'

The Python egg cache directory is currently set to:

  home2/minhhien/.python-eggs

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  You can
change the cache directory by setting the PYTHON_EGG_CACHE environment
variable to point to an accessible directory.

Comment: @dotiep0402, it seems you need to give permissions to the directory for apache2 to read. Please contact the support of your hosting company. Or open a new question about it.

Comment: Support reply: 
It seems this issue is related to a 3rd party application, but not to our hosting service. Unfortunately,
we do not offer free technical support for 3rd party software.

You will need to contact the application vendor/creator of your software for more information on this issue and its usage.

Have a nice day!

Comment: error mod_python, I installed package BitNami DjangoStack, no module mod_python, I dowloaded github !